# ? Java Script how to change the input value

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe frame on my page. I would like to do the following in Java Script:

Create episodes that you write from 1 to 30, you print a number after a number, not all of them, one batch.
In the input form in the velue = "" then you press the button automatically after each number

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form name="login" action="http://h.com/login" method="post"onsubmit="returndoLogin()">
     <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="http://www.msftconnecttest.com/redirect">
     <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true">
      <div class="form-title">
        <p>yahya00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field" >
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
       *<input id="yaas-poo" type="text" onblur="this.value=Re(this.value);"placeholder="yahya" 
          name="username" **value=""** required="">*
      </div>
      <div class="input-old">
       <i class="icon-lock"></i>
       <input type="hidden" name="password" placeholder="yahya2">
      </div>
      <div class="submit">
       <button type="submit">yahya3</button>
      </div>
     </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```